# Validating iOS app store receipts: also validate Apple Root CA certificate?

Tags: ios, validation, ssl, app-store, in-app-purchase

To validate that an iOS app store receipt is valid, you use the Apple Root CA certificate to check that it has not been modified. However, a hacker could theoretically replace the root CA in the app bundle, and Apple recommends that you should verify the security of the root cert as well. How would one go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How best to store Apple Root Certificates for receipt validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592682/how-best-to-store-apple-root-certificates-for-receipt-validation)